# What is @Override for in Java?

Tags: java, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do you use Java’s @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

Is there any reason to annotate a method with `@Override` other than to have the compiler check that the superclass has that method?

Comment: Also extensively answered in http://stackoverflow.com/q/94361/697630

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As you describe, @Override creates a compile-time check that a method is being overridden.  This is very useful to make sure you do not have a silly signature issue when trying to override.

For example, I have seen the following error:

```
public class Foo {
  private String id;
  public boolean equals(Foo f) { return id.equals(f.id);}
}
```

This class compiles as written, but adding the @Override tag to the equals method will cause a compilation error as it does not override the equals method on Object.  This is a simple error, but it can escape the eye of even a seasoned developer

Answer (score 25):

It not only makes the compiler check - although that would be enough to make it useful; it also documents the developer's intention.

For instance, if you override a method but don't use it anywhere from the type itself, someone coming to the code later may wonder why on earth it's there. The annotation explains its purpose.

Comment: I wonder what were your reputation points when you answered this question.

Comment: @OmarTariq: At a rough guess, about 50K I suspect.

Comment: @OmarTariq is this answer incorrect? What did you mean with your comment?

Answer (score 12):

Nope, you pretty much nailed it.

`@Override` tells the compiler your *intent*: if you tag a method `@Override`, you intended to override something from the superclass (or interface, in Java 6). A good IDE will helpfully flag any method that overrides a method without `@Override`, so the combination of the two will help ensure that you're doing what you're trying to.

Answer (score 2):

nope -- except that it also improves readability (i.e. in addition to whatever indicator your IDE uses, it makes it easy to spot that a method overrides a declaration in the superclass)